# Korn conditional operator not working

Tags: ksh

I wrote a small korn script, but when I try to run the script, it will not echo the message I want to display. When I try to run it by

```
ksh script.sh -1
```

it is not echoing the message.

```
if [ $# -le 0 ]
    then
        echo "That is a negative integer!"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: Is it bash or ksh?  Those are two different languages!

Comment: Whoops, I meant korn shell. I will edit it now.

Comment: How can number of arguments be negative?

Comment: @karakfa : Indeed, he was looking to check the first param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash/ksh `$#` represents the number of arguments passed as parameters.
What you needed is

```
if [ ${1:-0} -lt 0 ] # $1 is the first parameter
    then
        echo "That is a negative integer!"
    exit
fi
```

Or a shorted version of the above

```
[ ${1:-0} -lt 0 ] && echo "That is a negative integer!" && exit
```

**Edit 1**

- I have used shell [[ parameter expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) `${1:-0}` supply a default value.
- Since zero is technically not a negative number, replace `-le` with `-lt`

**Edit 2**

If you're looking forward to match a particular string then do below

```
[ ${1:-NULL} =  "StringToMatch" ] && DoSomething
```

If you're looking to see if the output is just has atleast one non-digit character,then do something like below

```
[[ {1:-NULL} =~  [^[:digit:]]+ ]] && DoSomething
```

<sup>**Warning :** Not all expansions mentioned in the link may not be supported by `ksh`</sup>

Comment: Thanks, will select your answer, works like a charm!

Comment: @user3807468  : I've made an edit, please see to it :)

Comment: Just a quick question, I am trying to now detect if the input was a string. How would I do that? I'm trying to look it up and I cannot find anything about it. I tried writing this down, but when I input any number, it rejects it.

'code'     [ $1 != ^[0-9] ]

Comment: @user3807468 : There are two implications of saying `was a string`. are you looking forward to match a particular string or are you looking to see if it is any string. In the second case,what is your definition of a string. for me `Bond009`,`7`,`A` are all valid strings.